# How to generate docs with the new style?

Tags: documentation, style, workbench, version-11

Is there a way to make the Wolfram Workbench generate HTML with the new documentation styles of version 11.1?

Comment: If you generate docs, and use them in Mathematica 11.1, do they appear as the old documentation style?

Comment: I'm talking about HTML

Comment: No, there isn't. *It requires a Workbench update.* I do hope though that any such update will preserve full compatibility with older versions of Mathematica, at least back to 10.0. I want documentation that works in any version between 10.0 - 11.1.